# Upload image from android sd card to php server

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to upload image file from sdcard to php server. So while uploading i got internal server error 500. I had created uploads folder in server also. But image is not upload to the particular folder.

My Code:

```
 TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/storage/sdcard0/";
    final String uploadFileName = "temp.jpg";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://example.com/android/uploadserver.php";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         } 
        }
```

And Php coding is:

```
       < ?php
   $file_path = "uploads/";
   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "success";
   } 
   else{
       echo "fail";
   }
   ? >
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
have you mentioned this permission in manifest?

Comment: as i know this code is from androidexample.com tutorial you copy pasted from it m i right?

Comment: yes..i have mentioned it

Comment: first you must understand what is your error you are getting 500 response code do you know what it means?

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

please visit this link it will clear your doubts

Comment: i referred that link,. not copy paste..

Comment: ok i also used same code but i didnt get any error while i used it . do you have your own server? if yes then please try this code for your own server hopefully you will not get this error cause i tried for my own an i didnt got any error if you dont have then you can use local server on your machine too like wamp(for window)

Comment: am not sure may be this error coming due to configurational issue of server may be am wrong but i hope this is the issue

Comment: yes i have my own server. i used in it only..

Comment: k then use your server in code i think your using other server? please relook into it

Comment: no..no..no..i am using my server only.. but in above i haven't mentioned it..

Comment: then i think you not properly configured your server or your path to server is may be missmatched please relook into it  chek slashes ,,spelling hope there is missmatching

Comment: @Divya I think its the server side issue, not client side, your code looks fine, 500 error means your request is not finding given server path. Just double check it.

Comment: my path is correct..

Comment: @Divya then it must not be occur dear, its the http error, so either you are testing without internet connection or you have wrong path

Comment: @pratik My server side path is correct.

Comment: @Divya Then there may be some configuration issue, as per my thought its the problem in server side. Have you declared Internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Any other solutions???

Comment: @Divya have you done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, i found my answer.

```
package com.ipot.image_upload;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     ImageView viewImage;
        Button b,upp;
        String ppath;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        private int serverResponseCode = 0;
        private String upLoadServerUri = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        upp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.up);

        upLoadServerUri="http://server.com/android/upload_image.php";

        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        upp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("path value..."+ppath);

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                //messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                int y=uploadFile(ppath);
                }
}).start();  
            }
        });
    }

  /*  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

      private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {

                     System.out.println("before call ...");
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions); 

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator+"temp.jpg";
                          //  + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";

                    System.out.println("image path..."+path);

                    ppath=path;

                    //uploadFile(ppath);

                  //  f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");

                String selectedImagePath;
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImage);

                System.out.println("before set image...");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
               // uploadFile(ppath);
                System.out.println("image path from gallery..."+selectedImagePath);

                ppath=selectedImagePath;
            }
        }
    }

    public int uploadFile(String ppath2) {

         String fileName = ppath2;

         HttpURLConnection conn = null;
         DataOutputStream dos = null;  
         String lineEnd = "\r\n";
         String twoHyphens = "--";
         String boundary = "*****";
         int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
         byte[] buffer;
         int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
         File sourceFile = new File(ppath2); 

         if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

              dialog.dismiss(); 

              Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+ppath);

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    //  messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ ppath);
                  }
              }); 

              return 0;

         }
         else
         {
              try { 

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                  URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                  // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                  conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                  conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                  conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                  dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                  dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                  dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                  dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                  // create a buffer of  maximum size
                  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                  buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                  // read file and write it into form...
                  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                  while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                   }

                  // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                  dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                  dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                  // Responses from the server (code and message)
                  serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                  String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                  Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                          + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                  if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                               String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                     +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                               //messageText.setText(msg);
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       });                
                  }    

                  //close the streams //
                  fileInputStream.close();
                  dos.flush();
                  dos.close();

             } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                 dialog.dismiss();  
                 ex.printStackTrace();

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 });

                 Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
             } catch (Exception e) {

                 dialog.dismiss();  
                 e.printStackTrace();

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         //messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 });
                 Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
             }
             dialog.dismiss();       
             return serverResponseCode; 

          } // End else block 
        }


    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if( uri == null ) {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }
        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();

    }   
}
```

And my php code is,

```
<?php
$target_path1 = "uploads/";
$randno=mt_rand(1,15000);
/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename($randno.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The first file ".  basename($randno. $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded.";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
}
?>
```

Thanks for all!!!

Answer (score 1):

> error 500 (internal server error) problem is caused server side not
>   client side. Please to try get the response code it will 500.
>   Ultimately it should be handled at server side not client. so please
>   test your web service first

OR

[see this](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

Comment: Vaishali, I think you are right, 500 means path not exist on server, so It must be a server side issue, not client side.

Comment: @ pratik yes.. i have test it in my demo app.. 
and if it right then please up Vote

Comment: vaishali, ya its ok, but then also someone downvoted your answer already...:)

Comment: @ pratik .. yes buddy :(

Comment: My server path is correct..But what else the problem??

Comment: @Divya I thought problem is in your server only. Is your domain is perfectly fine: example.com?

Comment: :D not much...buddy..hehe

Comment: @Divya is "Android" server located perfect on your server? Just go step by step and check

Comment: @ pratik thank you so much for upVote and @ Divya .. check your webservice please , might be you were missing some perameter to pass

Comment: @Vaishali you most welcome, its the right answer, so ek upvote to banta he yaar

Comment: @Vaishali ya ok, in which chatroom but?

Comment: @Divya yes do as like this http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/08/upload-files-from-android-to-server.html

Another solution is that upload image using MultipartEntity